# frame rate: relationship between FPS and MS (milliseconds needed to render a frame) in stats plugin

Tags: javascript, three.js, requestanimationframe

I'm using the Stats.js plugin to monitor my three.js performance.

The FPS (frames rendered in the last second) and MS (Milliseconds needed to render a frame) information does not seem to fit together:

[image: screenshot of stats.js plugin]

Per my calculation, if I need 4 MS to render a frame, then I should be able to render 1000 MS / 4 MS = 250 frames per second, which is far more than what RequestAnimationFrame provides, but a lot higher than the reported 17 FPS by the stats plugin.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a newer version of stats.js.

You have a screen with a refresh rate of 60Hz (or possibly 59Hz). That translates to an average of 16.67 ms/frame (or 16.95 ms/frame for 59 Hz).

The version of the script that you are using is incorrectly showing the time for each frame as FPS instead of the number of frames per second.